# How to auto swap columns if name contains a period

Tags: excel

My team inputs data in different ways which affects how long it takes for me to clean up lists for marketing. I attached a picture of what I am trying to do.

Essentially, I am needing a script that auto-switches names in columns A and B if column A does not contain a `.`. As you can see in the picture Linda & Jim do not have a `.` and are in the last name column. This list is about 9,000 people so trying to find a faster way to do this than manual.

Thanks.

[image]

I have tried many things. But I am not an expert.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We're here to help as soon as you can show us what code you've written so far, so don't forget to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: Just make two new columns, use `IF(...)` to select the values of A or B as appropriate, then (if you must) copy those new columns' values back to A and B.

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 new columns in the table, like such:

| Customer Last Name | Customer First Name | New Last Name | New First Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brown. | Justin |  |  |
| Luzkow. | Jennifer |  |  |
| Woodall. | Sandra |  |  |
| Heald. | Teresa and David |  |  |
| Gonzalez. | Rafael and Janet |  |  |
| Watson. | Karen |  |  |
| Atkins. | Shirly |  |  |
| Newberry. | Linda |  |  |
| Darcy. | Paul |  |  |
| Linda & Jim | Vitale. |  |  |

In the `New Last Name` column, I created this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",A2)),A2,B2)
```

and in the `New First Name` column, I created this (very similar) formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",A2)),B2,A2)
```

This works, by searching the text for a `.` character using the `SEARCH` function, if the `SEARCH` function returns a number, then I know that there is a `.` character in the text, otherwise, there isn't one. From there, I just select the column I need the text from (A2 or B2 in this case). Once you have all the data in the new columns, you can Copy and Paste Values into the original 2 columns if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in a Module, and select the sheet where the datas are

```vb
Sub changer()
For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows
If InStr(1, Cells(r.Row, 1), ".") = 0 Then
backcell = Cells(r.Row, 1)
Cells(r.Row, 1) = Cells(r.Row, 2)
Cells(r.Row, 2) = backcell
End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft 365, you can use this function.

Enter into a single cell, and the results will `SPILL` into the output range.

Note that I create a table named `Names`

```
=LET(
    nms, MAP(
        Names[Customer Last Name],
        Names[Customer First Name],
        LAMBDA(a, b,
            IF(RIGHT(a) = ".", a & "~" & b, b & "~" & a)
        )
    ),
    ln, BYROW(nms, LAMBDA(arr, TEXTBEFORE(arr, "~"))),
    fn, BYROW(nms, LAMBDA(arr, TEXTAFTER(arr, "~"))),
    VSTACK(Names[#Headers], HSTACK(ln, fn))
)
```

[image]